# Pandas difference between xlsx and XLSX

Tags: python, pandas

I am simply reading an excel file with name as abc.XLSX and then writing it is 
`writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('myFile.XLSX')`.
It is giving below error:
ValueError: No engine for filetype: 'XLSX'

But if I do :
`writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('myFile.xlsx')` it is working fine.

Don't know what is the difference between `xlsx` and `XLSX`. Any Suggestions?

Comment: no i checked the properties it extension only. I am able to read XLSX file but failing in write operation.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood the problem. But why do you want to write the extension in capitalized form?

Comment: Actually i just want to handle this Scenario because it is possible one.

Comment: Looks like you found a pandas bug

Answer (score 6):

Pandas [tries to auto-detect](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-excel-files) what Excel engine to use based on the file extension, and I guess does so in a case-sensitive way.

If you have `xlsxwriter` installed I think you might be able to do `df.to_excel('myFile.XLSX', engine='xlsxwriter')`.

Alternatively you could write it with the lower case extension and then rename the file if Pandas won't play ball with the upper case extension.